# Imagick library in windows (XAMPP)

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, pdf, imagick

I have been trying to use Imagick to convert a PDF file (base64/blob) to an image. But I receive an error when executing the code. I am using XAMPP in Windows. This is the error I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/458 in C:\xampp\htdocs\conversion\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\conversion\index.php(4): Imagick->readImageBlob('iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\conversion\index.php on line 4
```

And this is my code:

```
<?php
//Convert base64 pdf to image
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImageBlob('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');
$imagick->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$imageBlob = $imagick->getImageBlob();
echo $imageBlob; die();
?>
```

In the example, I am not using a base64 pdf file but an base64 image I found on the internet

[image]

Comment: If you want to use the `Imagick` class from the root namespace, you either need to import it (`use Imagick;`), or call it using a backslash (`new \Imagick()`) - as you do it with all other PHP classes

Comment: Ok. I have already tried with those two methods, but now I get this error: https://prnt.sc/OGmIANfNekfS

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, including both the code you are currently using and the error message you are facing

Comment: Done. I did an edit

Comment: Please also share the error message **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve it. As far as I read the image, the error is thrown at a completely different line of code

Comment: I did an edit that shows the error message. That's all that codeigniter is giving me. I am trying with a base64 image because I did not want to use a very long string like the one I have for the PDF. But it does not work with a base64 PDF file neither

Comment: Please share more details. The code you've shared does not contain any CodeIgniter relevant parts. It does not generate any response after all, and it does not contain the code that generates the given error

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. I created a new project with that code alone (without the Codeigniter framework) and it is not working still. I think the problem might be related to the Imagick installation.